# python split string into letters, numbers and special chars

Tags: python, regex, split, python-re

I have following function want to split string into words. The split result needs to separate letters, numbers and some special chars like / or -

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def split_string_with_letters_and_non_letters(input_string):
    split_strings = re.split(r"([a-zA-Z] )+", input_string)

    result = []
    count = 0
    for x in split_strings:
        if x not in result and x != ' ' and x != '':
            result.append(x.lower().strip())
            count=count+1

    delim = "|"
    result_string = delim.join([str(ele) for ele in result])
    
    return result_string

teststring= "SPRINTER2500 2WD C E-150"
print(split_string_with_letters_and_non_letters(teststring))`
```

my expected return result is:

```
"SPRINTER|2500|2|WD|C|E|-|150"
```

Comment: are you looking for a regex solution or would a simple state machine also work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your regex. Here is revisited code:

```py
import re

def split_string_with_letters_and_non_letters(input_string):
    #new regex
    split_strings = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+|[/|-]', input_string)

    # Remove empty elements
    result = [x for x in split_strings if x]
    # Join with a delimiter
    result_string = "|".join(result)
    
    return result_string

teststring = "SPRINTER2500 2WD C E-150"
print(split_string_with_letters_and_non_letters(teststring))
```

Result:

```
SPRINTER|2500|2|WD|C|E|-|150
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex approach using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a custom character classifier:

```
from itertools import groupby

def char_type(c):
    if c.isalpha(): return 'alpha'
    if c.isdigit(): return 'digit'
    if c.isspace(): return
    if c in {'-', '/'}: return 'special' # this is just an example
    return 'other'

out = '|'.join(''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(input_string, char_type) if k)
```

Output:

```
'SPRINTER|2500|2|WD|C|E|-|150'
```

If you just want to use the standard unicode classes and drop the spaces use [`unicodedata.category`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) and exclude `Zs`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import unicodedata

out = '|'.join(''.join(g) for k, g in
               groupby(input_string, unicodedata.category)
               if k!='Zs')
```

*NB. this separates the lowercase/uppercase characters into different groups, you can however use `lambda x: unicodedata.category(x.casefold())` in place of `unicodedata.category` to avoid that.*

Comment: I never used this package before. But it works great. I will do some research about this new way.